# Laravel database configuration working on local machine but not in google cloud

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel, laravel-4, google-cloud-sql

Hi I am using google app engine with cloud sql and I am having trouble deploying my laravel based app.

Everything works on my local machine but I am not able to query databases when deploying it to the cloud.  I get the following error.

InvalidArgumentException
Database [phlingo_user] not configured.

This is what I have in \app\config\database.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
    $u_array = array(
        'driver'        =>  'mysql',
        'unix_socket'   =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE'),
        'host'          =>  '',
        'database'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_U_DB_NAME'),
        'username'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'       =>  'utf8',
        'collation'     =>  'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'        =>  ''
    );
    $c_array = array(
        'driver'        =>  'mysql',
        'unix_socket'   =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE'),
        'host'          =>  '',
        'database'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_C_DB_NAME'),
        'username'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'       =>  'utf8',
        'collation'     =>  'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'        =>  ''
    );
    $p_array = array(
        'driver'        =>  'mysql',
        'unix_socket'   =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE'),
        'host'          =>  '',
        'database'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_P_DB_NAME'),
        'username'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'       =>  'utf8',
        'collation'     =>  'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'        =>  ''
    );
} else {
    $u_array = array(
        'driver'    =>  'mysql',
        'host'      =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST'),
        'database'  =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_U_DB_NAME'),
        'username'  =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'  =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   =>  'utf8',
        'collation' =>  'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    =>  ''
    );
    $c_array = array(
        'driver'    =>  'mysql',
        'host'      =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST'),
        'database'  =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_C_DB_NAME'),
        'username'  =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'  =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   =>  'utf8',
        'collation' =>  'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    =>  ''
    );
    $p_array = array(
        'driver'    =>  'mysql',
        'host'      =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST'),
        'database'  =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_P_DB_NAME'),
        'username'  =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'  =>  getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   =>  'utf8',
        'collation' =>  'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    =>  ''
    );
}

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => 'phlingo_user',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => array(

        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

                getenv('MYSQL_U')      =>  $u_array,

                getenv('MYSQL_C')      =>  $c_array,

                getenv('MYSQL_P')   =>  $p_array,

        'pgsql' => array(
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'forge',
            'username' => 'forge',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ),

        'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => array(

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => array(
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ),

    ),

);
```

[phlingo_user] is referring to $u_array.  Am I missing something to complete the configuration?

Comment: Are those environmental variables set in your app.yaml? You can set them right in your laravel config file to make things easy. Google is going to lock down security for you when connecting to a cloud sql instance.

Comment: No they are not.  Laravel doesn't detect environmental variables set in the app.yaml.  They are however located in the root folder in a file called .env.php which the laravel platform uses

Comment: I haven't tried the .env.php stuff for my laravel apps on GAE so not sure if they work. Im using a gae folder in config and it works fine. I would put the info in directly now to test with. Your going to have more work moving the storage paths and getting them to work right.

Comment: alright I did that and it worked but I'm still wondering how you are able to access the environmental variables from your app.yaml in your laravel app? I'm using laravel 4.2 what did you add to your config folder?

Comment: @user3813559 Can u send me ur email, i want to ask you something about Laravel with Google SQL

Answer (score 1):

This might provide a useful example:
https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/ .

As described in that post, you can define env variables in your app.yaml and then modify your database.php file to access them.  It looks like you might be missing the app.yaml part of your setup.
In the context of an app engine project (including running locally on the development server), these vars will be set and accessible.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work for the latest iteration of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar difficulty trying to deploy my application on App engine. I will share with you how I fixed it.

- remove routes from api.php (I didn't need these for my application)
- enable cloud SQL api [enable](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin&redirect=https:%2F%2Fconsole.cloud.google.com&_ga=2.164522367.-1360075521.1510572080)
- Follow this tutorial [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible)  **follow next two steps before deploying**
- make the following changes to the composer.json file. The tutorial is incorrect.
  ```
  "post-install-cmd": [
              "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
              "php artisan optimize",
              "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache"
          ]
  ```
- Configure your app.yaml file like so:
  ```
  runtime: php
  env: flex

  runtime_config:
    document_root: public

  env_variables:
    # Put production environment variables here.
    APP_ENV: production
    APP_LOG: errorlog
    APP_KEY: APP_KEY (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    CACHE_DRIVER: database
    SESSION_DRIVER: database
    ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
    DB_HOST: localhost
    DB_PORT: 3306
    DB_CONNECTION: mysql
    DB_DATABASE: DATABASE_NAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_USERNAME: USERNAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)

    QUEUE_DRIVER: database

  beta_settings:
      # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
      # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
      cloud_sql_instances: "YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
  ```